# Meteor.startup() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to use some jQuery in my Meteor app, but the jQuery below

```
   Meteor.startup(function(){

        $('#new-list-button').on('click', function(ev){
            console.log('clicked');
        })
    });
```

runs before the `#new-list-button` element loads on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually thats an on click event

Meteor have his own event handlers

```
Template.example.events({
 'click #new-list-button':function(){
   console.log('clicked');
  }
})
```

Take a look into [Templates.events](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events) docs

FYI if you want to use jQuery plugins on meteor i suggest you to use the [rendered function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_rendered).

For example

```
Template.example.rendered = function(){
  initializePlugin();
}
```

Comment: Im trying to use jQuery capabilities though.  I want to add a class on click

Comment: @redress well just add the code inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.example.events({
 'click #new-list-button':function(event){
    $('yourElem').addClass('yourClass');
  }
});
```

Jquery works inside meteor events, you just have to look at it differently as opposed to `on.click`